# Undefined position index when I use onPageScrollStateChanged

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I use onPageScrollStateChanged={onPageScroll} the position is

```
 const onPageScroll = (event: any) => {
        const {position} = event.nativeEvent;
        if (position !== currentPage) {
          setCurrentPage(position);
        }
        console.log(position);
      };
```